# Problem invoking WLST - java.lang.RuntimeException: error in finding weblogic.Home

Tags: jython, wlst

I am getting this error while trying to run the following WLST script :

```
"Problem invoking WLST - java.lang.RuntimeException: error in finding weblogic.Home"
```

However I have run the `setWLSEnv.sh` before running the script.

Comment: Can you give more details how you are running your wlst script ?

Answer (score 0):

- This problem has been solved by using the following argument with garbage collection script:
  /opt/SP/oracle/product/fmw/java/bin/java -cp /opt/SP/oracle/product/fmw/wlserver_10.3/server/lib/weblogic.jar  weblogic.WLST /opt/SP/oracle/home/scripts/runGC.py
- Note: /opt/SP/oracle/product is the oracle middleware installation directory.